# How can you predict your rails project system usage?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, digital-ocean

Is there a way to calculate what the system requirements will be for running my rails app? (= Monthly cost)

I'm mainly interested in either Heroku or Digital Ocean.

Comment: Can you predict how many users you will get?

Comment: I have the amount of users and know in what time period the peek will be. However I'm not looking for a calculation on this specific project but rather a general formula (which doesn't have to be exact, hosting comes in packages anyways).

Comment: In which case I would suggest doing some performance testing and measuring what resources your application needs. Any other answer here would be pure speculation.

Answer (score 1):

I would propose two ways of doing that:
Here the simple and not so accurate way:
1. Download the Apache at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html
2. Install your application on a $5 or free trial Digital Ocean droplet.
3. Run ab with the estimated user amount on a page which is dynamically generated like this

```
    ab -n 10 -c 20 http://www.yourdigitaloceanserver.com/hugeerbfromdatabase
```

where "n" stands for the amount of request you do with "c" concurrent users (20 in this case). Then you take the test results and see if you are satisfied with the speed. If not you need a bigger server.

There is sure no certain rule as the performance of your application depends on multiple factors such as concurrency, number of unicorn works (or other web servers), database queries, caching or not caching, using redis or memcached and so on (I could write a book about it).

The other way would be probably more accurate. Grab a tool like mechanize and created a threaded application which does things on your site you expect users to do and measure the response times. As you can scale Digital Ocean instances on the fly you can let it grow as your traffic grows.

If you don't have a ready to go app yet just install Ruby on Rails on a droplet and do a simple:

```
    rails new mytestapp
    cd mytestapp
    rails g scaffold things name 
    rake db:migrate
    rails c
    100.times do
       Thing.create!(name: "lorem ipsum")
    end
    exit
    rails s
```

Now run from a different shell or computer:

```
    ab -n 10 -c 20 http://www.yourdigitaloceanserver.com:3000/things
```

And you get an idea about the performance. You can also try a different server like puma etc. 
Good luck